# How to add a class to an input with checkbox?

Tags: angular

```
    //here is my app.component.html code 

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <form #todoForm= "ngForm"(ngSubmit)="todoSubmit(todoForm.value);todoForm.resetForm()">
            <div class="form-group">
              <h1 class="text-center text-primary">Todo App</h1>
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Todo" name="todo" [(ngModel)]="value">
                <span class="input-group-text" (click)="addTodo()"><i class="material-icons">add</i></span>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I want to bind an input with a checkbox to a CSS class using [ngClass] in Angular so that when the user clicks on the checkbox the line-through should be fired! I want to add the class(.is-done) with the condition on my app.html

```
            <div [ngClass]= "'is-done'">
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li *ngFor="let todo of todos">
                  {{todo}}
                  <i class="material-icons" (click)="deleteItem(todo)">delete</i>
                  <input type="checkbox" (click)="onToggle()">
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

on the TS code, I have added a function so that when then the user clicks data should change to the opposite

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})


export class AppComponent  {
  value: string;
  todos = [];
  data = false;

 addTodo(value) {
    if(value !== ""){
    this.todos.push(this.value)
    } else {
      alert ("do something!")
    }
  }

  deleteItem(todo) {
    for (let i=0; i <= this.todos.length; i++) {
      if(todo == this.todos[i]){
        this.todos.splice(i, 1)
      }
    }
  }

  todoSubmit(value: any) {
    if(value !== ""){
      this.todos.push(this.value)
    } else {
      alert('do something !')
    }
  }

  onToggle(data) {
    this.data = !this.data;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Mate, I dont really get to what condition .is-done should be bind to. The usual syntax for ngClass should look like this --> [ngClass]="{'is-done': if any condition is true}". If u tell me what condition should be bind I could give u example code. best regards

Comment: Ahh okay u want to bind to data? --> then [ngClass]="{'is-done': data}"

Answer (score 0):

Given that that you want the class `is-done` to be bound to whether or not the value of your checkbox is true, we can do this by using your existing code and adding the following:

You have the existing checkbox in your **template**

```
<input type="checkbox" (click)="onToggle()">
```

and in your **component**, `onToggle()` can look like

```
data: boolean = false;
onToggle(){
    this.data = !this.data; // flips the value of data
}
```

we can then apply the css of class `is-done` dynamically (only applied when `data === true`, ie when the checkbox is checked) like so:

```
<div class="data" [class.is-done]="data">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

and now, checking the checkbox sets the value of `data`, and will cause the css of the class `is-done` to be applied to the div when `data === true`.

Comment: this might be confusing! but the Div class is not the same as the CSS class, I edited the code!

Comment: Could it be that u want to cross out any todo thats done?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, according to the information you supplied I try to solve your problem. For me it seems like you want to cross out any todo item thats done. Therefore you have 2 options, you could add a status variable to the todo model like so:

**todo.model.ts**

```
export class Todo {
   title: string;
   done: boolean;

   constructor(title: string, done: boolean) {
       this.title = title;
       this.done = done;
   }
}
```

You should add a structure like **shared/models/todo.model.ts**, add the above code. Also add an index.ts to the same folder(models) like so:

**index.ts**

```
export * from './todo.model';
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

import { Todo } from 'path'; // Path to models folder, where index.ts resides, that is exporting the model


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})


export class AppComponent  {
  value: string;
  todos: Todo[] = []; // Init an empty array of Todo Items

 addTodo(value) {
    if(value !== ""){
    this.todos.push(new Todo(value, false)); // Construct a new Todo Item anytime you add a new one
    } else {
      alert ("do something!")
    }
  }

  deleteItem(todo) {
    for (let i=0; i <= this.todos.length; i++) {
      if(todo == this.todos[i]){
        this.todos.splice(i, 1)
      }
    }
  }

  todoSubmit(value: any) {
    if(value !== ""){
      this.todos.push(new Todo(value, false)); // same as mentioned above
    } else {
      alert('do something !')
    }
  }
}
```

**then in your app.component.html:**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li *ngFor="let todo of todos" [ngClass]= "{'is-done': todo.done}">
     {{todo}}
     <i class="material-icons" (click)="deleteItem(todo)">delete</i>
     <input type="checkbox" (click)="todo.done = !todo.done">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Set it to done if the user clicks on the checkbox, then bind the property to the css class with ngClass.

Remember, to make this work you need a class Todo and set the initial value of the todo to false/true. The class represents your todo item and should consist of any attribute you would want to add to your todo, like a title: string, description: string, timestamp: Date, done: boolean

Hopefully this answers your question.

P.S.: The second approach would involve building an own component todo-item.component, but still you would want to have a class Todo thats consisting of the above mentioned attributes (and more if u need it).

**I also added a Stackblitz and implemented the wanted behaviour here:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-bndwdk

Best regards,

Sagat

Comment: it still doesn`t work, when I click on the checkbox I get this message on the console {TypeError: Cannot create property 'done' on string 'JavaScript'}

Comment: Yes, I guess cause u didnt provide an object. I will edit my answer ans u can try again.

Comment: I made several edits to the todo.model.ts and app.component.ts. The Error you see in the console results from the fact that u try to set a boolean property on a string not an Object. Please think also about OOP when you start programming, cause in this world, anything is about objects (domain objects). regards :)